# Will order by preserve?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table source_table (id number);
insert into source_table values(3);
insert into source_table values(1); 
insert into source_table values(2);

create table target_table (id number, seq_val number);
create sequence example_sequence;

insert into target_table 
select id, example_sequence.nextval
    from 

> (select id from source_table ***order by id***);
```

Is it officially assured that for the id's with the lower values in source_table corresponding sequence's value will also be lower when inserting into the source_table? In other words, is it guaranteed that the sorting provided by ***order by*** clause will be preserved when inserting?

***EDIT***
The question is not: 'Are rows ordered in a table as such?' but rather 'Can we rely on the **order by** clause used in the subquery when inserting?'.

To even more closely illustrate this, the contents of the `target table` in the above example, after running the query like `select * from target_table order by id` would be:

`ID | SEQ_VAL
  1   1
  2   2
  3   3`

Moreover, if i specified descending ordering when inserting like this:

```
insert into target_table 
select id, example_sequence.nextval
    from 

> (select id from source_table ***order by id DESC***);
```

The output of the same query from above would be:
`ID | SEQ_VAL
  1   3
  2   2
  3   1`

Of that I'm sure, I have tested it multiple times. My question is 'Can I always rely on this ordering?'

Comment: SQL is explicit in that its data-sets are unordered data-sets.  Ordering in this sense is never *guaranteed* to be preserved.  The `order by` *must* be in the same scope as the `INSERT` : `INSERT INTO tgt SELECT id, s.nextval FROM src ORDER BY id`

Comment: That's what I thought at first as well. But when testing I always got correct ordering. Hence my question was raised. Is it officially confirmed to work that way every time.

Comment: No, it will often, even normally, work, just because it's convenient for the database.  But it's never a guarantee.

Comment: This will definitively fail if you use a *parallel insert*.

Comment: So there is no way to assign `example_sequence.nextval` in the way I wanted when posting the question?

Answer (score 3):

Tables in a relational database are not ordered, and any *apparent* ordering in the result set of a cursor which lacks an `ORDER BY` is an artifact of data storage, is not guaranteed, and later actions on the table may cause this apparent ordering to change. If you want the results of a cursor to be ordered in a particular manner you **MUST** use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Oh but I do! Just in the subquery... .

Comment: Once it's stored in the table there is no ordering to the data. When you SELECT data from the table you created you must use an ORDER BY if you want the results in a particular order. Think of a table as if it's a bag, into which you toss your data - from across the room. It lands in the bag with considerable force, and the impact of the new data may cause old data to move - or perhaps the new data will end up on the top of the old data - or next to it. You have no guarantee of ordering. Use an ORDER BY whenever you SELECT data if you care about the order of the results.

Comment: The question as I undestod it is about assigning sequence ID in the same order as one column in the source table.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber that exactly what the question was about!.

Comment: Nevertheless thank you @BobJarvis for touching on very close related topic which is chaotic row placement in the table as such.

Comment: @M.Dawid IMO **use sequence** to assign few keys for lot of sessions. **Do not** use sequence to assign lot of keys for one session. So in this cas I'd try to avoid to use the sequence.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber while this might be true, my use case is different. It has nothing to do with sessions, but with file names and the date in which they were created.